# Prophet: Multiplicative seasonality scales down trend values

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I am having strange effects when I change my Prophet model from additive to multiplicative seasonality:
While my predictions get a lot better, my trend seems to be multiplied down to about 10% of the expected values.
I would expect the trend to stay in the same value range. Am I wrong?

Example with additive seasonality:

```
    proph_model = Prophet()
    proph_model.fit(df)
```

Result as expected:
[image]

Example with multiplicative seasonality:

```
    proph_model = Prophet( seasonality_mode="multiplicative" )
    proph_model.fit(df)
```

Result with better prediction but strangely scaled down trend:
[image]

I am currently working with latest Prophet 1.1.1 on Python 3.10.6.

Answer (score 0):

- for *additive seasonality* your assumption is that you add components (trend + seasonality) - the same amplitude and/or frequency over time; use when magnitude of seasonality does not change in relation to time
- for *multiplicative seasonality* your assumption is that you multiply components (trend * seasonality) - increasing or decreasing amplitude and/or frequency over time; use when magnitude of seasonality does change in relation to time

Having this, you can expect different behaviors of your model for different *seasonality_mode* settings. Only if the trend doesn't change much, then additive and multiplicative seasonalities give comparable results.

You can see more details of your model components using `proph_model.plot_components(forecast)`, maybe this will make whole picture more clear for you.

Another way to have the overview, is to decompose the timeseries:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df = df.set_index('ds') 

result_add = seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive')
result_add.plot()

result_m = seasonal_decompose(df, model='multiplicative')
result_m.plot()
```

I think that anyway, the best way to choose optimal parameters is to run cross validation to compare prediction error with multiplicative vs additive *seasonality_mode*.